# Django makemigrations check generates same migration

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I created a new model that has two foreign keys to existing models, nothing complex, ran makemigrations, and did a git push. After pushing, my Jenkins build failed immediately on account of a check migrations detecting more were needed. I ran makemigrations --check and sure enough a new migration appeared altering a field to my new model that did nothing but set it to what was already in the model. Running the command multiple times results in the same migration being generated every single time.

At a loss as to what is triggering this behavior.

I tried renaming the field and the same issue persists.

Only other thing to note is `CustomReference` is a model I recently renamed from `CustomReferenceNumber`.

Models:

```py
class CustomReference(BaseModelHardDelete):
    reference = models.CharField(max_length=constants.CHARFIELD_SIZE_256, null=False, blank=False)
    company_preferences = models.ForeignKey(CompanyPreferences, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='custom_references')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created_at',)
        unique_together = ('reference', 'company_preferences',)


class CustomReferenceValue(BaseModelHardDelete):
    custom_reference = models.ForeignKey('companies.CustomReference', null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    shipment = models.ForeignKey(Shipment, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='custom_reference_values')
    value = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created_at',)
        unique_together = ('custom_reference', 'shipment',)


class BaseModelHardDelete(TimeStampedModel):
    """
    Base model to use throughout the codebase
    Implements soft deletion and timestamping by default.
    Uses UUID as the PK
    """

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, verbose_name='ID')

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def __str__(self):
        return str(f'{self.__class__.__name__} ID: {self.id}')


class TimeStampedModel(models.Model):
    created_at = CreatedField()
    updated_at = LastModifiedField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Migrations 1:

```py
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('companies', '0113_auto_20190730_1544'),
        ('shipments', '0191_merge_20190729_2140'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='CustomReferenceValue',
            fields=[
                ('created_at', common.fields.CreatedField(default=django.utils.timezone.now, editable=False)),
                ('updated_at', common.fields.LastModifiedField(default=django.utils.timezone.now, editable=False)),
                ('id', models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('value', models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)),
                ('custom_reference', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='companies.CustomReference')),
                ('shipment', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, related_name='custom_reference_values', to='shipments.Shipment')),
            ],
            options={
                'ordering': ('created_at',),
            },
        ),
        migrations.AlterUniqueTogether(
            name='customreferencevalue',
            unique_together=set([('custom_reference', 'shipment')]),
        ),
    ]
```

Migration 2(this one gets generated over and over):

```py
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('shipments', '0192_auto_20190801_2102'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='customreferencevalue',
            name='custom_reference',
            field=models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='companies.CustomReference'),
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: Can you show the code for BaseModelHardDelete?

Comment: Added. Shouldn't have anything to do with the issue as it's used extensively throughout the codebase.

Comment: Show the error please